# Creating Self-Signed CA Certificate with makecert.exe

Tags: windows, ssl, ssl-certificate, makecert

I am trying to create Self-Signed CA Certificate on 32bit Windows 7 (virtual).
The makecert is v7.1 located in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin>`.

Whenever i try to execute this command (elevated) ...

```
makecert.exe -r -n “CN=MyCert CA” -pe -sv MyCert.pvk -a sha1 -len 2048
             -b 09/04/2012 -e 09/04/2018 -cy authority MyCert.cer
```

...I get prompted for password but when i confirm it I get:

> Error: CryptCertStrToNameW failed => 0x80092023 (-2146885597) Failed

Any help would be apreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I copied your command into a command prompt and got the same error. However, I retyped the command and it worked. I suspect one of the characters in the name argument `"CN=MyCert CA"` is a special character, possibly copied from a word processor.

Comment: I copied the text from notepad. But i tried several different names for CA (including without space) but did not help. Rewritting the whole command did the trick.

Comment: For those who found themselves here, like me--if you copypasted from a website, you've probably got unicody curly quotes (like OP--check the quotes around his CN) instead of the correct ascii version: "

Answer (score 12):

This is an old question, but it would appear that you're using word processor "smart quotes" rather than ASCII double quotes.

So the problem isn't with `makecert`, but with how you entered the command. The windows command shell, `cmd.exe`, doesn't see `“CN=MyCert CA”` as a quoted word. It instead sees two barewords, `“CN=MyCert` and `CA”`, with the "smart quotes" being part of the word.

- The ASCII straight double quote, `"` has a code point of U+0022 (aka '\x22' in C# or C).
- The left double "smart" quote", `“` has a code point of U+201C (aka '\u201C' in C#).
- The right double "smart" quote, `”` has a code point of U+201D (aka '\u201D' in C#).

And thus the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the same error if you don't have CN= in the name.

For example I had this error with `-n "My Name"` , but it succeeded with `-n "CN=My Name"`

Answer (score -2):

Wrong Way    =    “CN=MyCert CA”

Right Way    =    “CN=MyCert”

Right Way    =    “CN=NameOfCert”

12345432123454321

```
enter code here
```